# Принцип создания приложений в Django Python

Tags: python-3.x, django

Приступил к изучению Django, и столкнулся с проблемой понимания структуры создания сайта.

Допустим, создается проект Новый_супер_сайт. вызовом startproject

Django создал папки, подпапки, manage.py

Верно ли я понял, что если я хочу создать например следующее древо сайта:

```
   - Новый_супер_сайт:
                     - Информация_по_машинам
                                  - ...(Последующие переходы вглубь по "ссылкам")
                                  - ...
                     - Информация_по_вертолетам
                                  - ...(Последующие переходы вглубь по "ссылкам")
                                  - ...
                     - Информация_по_космолетам
                                  - ...(Последующие переходы вглубь по "ссылкам")
                                  - ...
```

То для каждой ветки "Информация_по_..." необходимо создавать свой startapp? Или же это реализуется иначе?

Большое спасибо!

@nomnoms12

Спасибо, касательно приложений, думаю понял.
Возник ещё один, подобный вопрос:
Когда я создаю проект: startproject, зайдя на локальный сервер могу проверить работоспособность. Далее создаю приложения, которые мне хотелось бы видеть. Получается вид проекта следующий:

```
- Новый_супер_сайт: [startproject ...]
    - Информация_по_машинам [startapp ...]
    - Информация_по_вертолетам [startapp ...]
    - ...
```

Не пойму, как реализуются ссылки в таком случае, т.е.:

```
www.Новый_супер_сайт.ru - это пустая страница?
www.Новый_супер_сайт.ru/Информация_по_машинам - оформленная страница
```

Вопрос получается такой, во всех "уроках",что я просмотрел на сегодняшний день, мы создаем приложения, но не могу понять, как оформить(создать представление) ту самую стартовую страницу? - www.Новый_супер_сайт.ru

Пример с кодом файла Новый_супер_сайт/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ??? ), # Что я должен вписать тут, для оформления стартовой страницы?
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
```

]

Comment: В Вашем случае все 3 приложения предоставляют информацию по каким-то объектам. Мне кажется, было бы целесообразней объединить их в одно, но с несколькими моделями. В общем же случае, Вы правы, Вам стоит создавать по приложению для каждого логически обособленного набора файлов.

Comment: При желании можно хоть одно приложение с одной моделью Page сделать, а древо реализовать с помощью поля parent_page, в котором модель Page ссылается сама на себя. Всё зависит от того, что вы с этим древом собираетесь делать дальше — хватит ли одного приложения и одной модели для вашей задачи или не хватит.

Comment: Если вам прям очень принципиально выпихнуть каждую страницу сайта в отдельное приложение (но зачем), то никто не мешает сделать startapp indexpage для главной страницы

Comment: @andreymal Нет, дело не в принципиальности, а в том, что я просто не знаю, как это делается правильно, собственно, потому тут и спрашиваю :)

Comment: @fer0m всё зависит от ситуации, задач, связности, масштабов и личных предпочтений, некоторые сайты можно и целиком в один-единственный startapp запихнуть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вопрос получается такой, во всех "уроках",что я просмотрел на сегодняшний день, мы создаем приложения, но не могу понять, как оформить(создать представление) ту самую стартовую страницу? - www.Новый_супер_сайт.ru

Если вы уже знакомы с [`generic views`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/), то проще будет создать `View` для главной, где определить, какая информация и где будет располагаться (в шаблоне естественно).

```py
class MainView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = '<path_to_template>'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # ...
        # Если что-то надо поместить в контекст
        # ...
        return ctx
```

И эту вьюху указать как основную.

В принципе, можете использовать и просто функцию, но с `generic` писать меньше и удобнее.

---

> Верно ли я понял, что если я хочу создать например следующее древо сайта:
>   То для каждой ветки "Информация_по_..." необходимо создавать свой startapp? Или же это реализуется иначе?

Тут зависит от вашего желания. Можете создать хоть 100 приложений, но тогда вам будет сложнее их поддерживать.

Хорошим решением будет создание моделей категории и контента:

```py
class InfoCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', help_text='Например, "информация по вертолетам"')
    # ...

class InfoCategoryPage(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeighKey(to=InfoCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

В ссылках для организации урлов нужно будет указывать `id` или `slug` (если добавите поле `slug`), например для `Django 1.11` (для `Django 2.x` посмотрите в [доке](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) про `urlpatterns`):

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^category-(?P<cat_id>\d+)$', <вью категории>),
    url(r'^category-(?P<cat_id>\d+)/acticle-(?P<acticle_id>\d+)$', <вью страниц категории>),
    # ...
]
```

Тут придётся немного поработать напильником и проверять, что если нет категории или статьи в категории, то возвращать `404`.